# Regex vs, versus, vs., v. matching in lines for C# code

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write a regex that matches the word `versus`, `verse`, `vs.`, `v.`, `v` but `v` should not be jumbled in words.

```
@"\b((.*?)" + Regex.Unescape(xz) + @"[.,:/s]?)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
```

Here I'll pass the array and test it.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you close:

```
\b(?:(?:vers(?:e|us)|v)\b|vs\.|v\.)
```

One difficulty is in word boundaries vs. (heh) words that end in a period. See [Regex using word boundary but word ends with a . (period)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004955/regex-using-word-boundary-but-word-ends-with-a-period) for other options.

Note that "verse" can also mean "poetry" so there could be false positives.