# Querying records that start/end with a string, within word boundaries using REGEXP (MySql)

Tags: mysql, regex, stemming

In the below query, I'd like to find records that start with *engineer* . e.g. I'd like to pull back records with the description *engineer**ing***

```
SELECT * FROM app.desc_test t
WHERE lower(t.desc) REGEXP '[[:<:]]engineer[[:>:]]';
```

The word boundaries are properly handling all special characters (i.e. commas, spaces, special characters, etc that are before and after), but I'm not sure how to write the Regex so that it *starts with* engineer.

Also, how would I make this say starts with OR ends with engineer.

- Somewhat [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004955/regex-using-word-boundary-but-word-ends-with-a-period), but in .NET
- [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901704/mysql-regexp-word-boundaries-and-double-quotes), but looking for double quotes in MySQL
- MySQL 5.7 regex [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE desc_test (
>   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   desc varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (id)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
> ```

**Edit**
The value will be unknown/dynamic, so hardcoding any *"ing"* expression isn't the solution.

Comment: `REGEXP '[[:<:]]engineer(ing)?[[:>:]]'`? Or `REGEXP '[[:<:]]engineer[[:alpha:]]*[[:>:]]'`? Sorry, when you say "must start with", do you mean a word in a string should start with it, or the whole string should start with `engineer`?

Comment: You could omit the word-boundary pattern at the end: `'[[:<:]]engineer'` But keep in mind that the word-boundary patterns will not work on MySQL 8.0 because they have changed their regexp implementation. Just giving you a heads up in case you intend to upgrade, ever.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, should clarify that the string will be coming in dynamically. Will make an edit.

Comment: What you ultimately need is a `FULLTEXT` index that supports stemming, so it matches common English suffixes. But MySQL's FULLTEXT doesn't support stemming yet. There's a worklog associated with this feature, but it hasn't been begun yet: https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2423

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin, this is good insight.

Comment: You'll be happier with some kind of fulltext index, because using `REGEXP` is thousands of times slower than an indexed solution. See my presentation [Full Text Search Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql). You might need to move to some other database, or use a specialized search technology like ElasticSearch, which [supports stemming](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/stemming.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to match the beginning of the word, you can just remove `[[:>:]]` from the regexp.

```
SELECT * FROM app.desc_test t
WHERE lower(t.desc) REGEXP '[[:<:]]engineer';
```

Comment: This is a far simpler solution than mine.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: Full Text Search as referenced by [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54294970/querying-records-that-start-end-with-a-string-within-word-boundaries-using-rege/54295211#comment95410553_54294970) is preferred**

> because using REGEXP is thousands of times slower than an indexed solution

## But...

To use your current REGEXP implementation, your MySQL should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM app.desc_test t WHERE lower(t.desc) 
REGEXP '[[:<:]]engineer[a-z]*[[:>:]]';
```

The Regex looks like this:

```
[[:<:]]engineer[a-z]*[[:>:]]
```

Meaning:

> `[[:<:]]`  -  Start of word boundary  
>     `engineer` - The string given by the search (dynamic)
>     `[a-z]`    - any character between a-z between zero and any number of times. 
>      `*`       - The above "group" between zero and any number of times. 
>     `[[:>:]]`  - End of word boundary

The above should do what you need. You can also customise it for instance to include digits (`(a-z0-9)`), or whatever you wish.

---

## Revisions to this answer:

**One:**

*Revised, Improved: use `[[:alpha:]]` so:*

```
[[:<:]]engineer[[:alpha:]]*[[:>:]]
```

**Two:**

As correctly [pointed out by Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54295275/3536236) there is actually little need for excess REGEXP. Your word boundaries, or lack thereof, does your work for you.

Therefore to select any word beginning with `engineer` or ending with `engineer`, you simply make a REGEXP *OR* statement :

```
SELECT * FROM app.desc_test t WHERE lower(t.desc) 
REGEXP '([[:<:]]engineer)|(engineer)[[:>:]])'
```

This means:

Return true if:

- The term *engineer* comes at the start of a word, regardless of what comes after it.
- ***OR*** the term *engineer* comes at the end of a word, regardless of what comes before it.

This should fit exactly what you're looking for. This has been tested on MySQL 5.7.

---

Sources :

- [MYSQL 5.7 Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax)
- [MySQL REGEXP word boundaries [[:<:]] [[:>:]] and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901704/mysql-regexp-word-boundaries-and-double-quotes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Example cases:

> ```
> Engineer
> ```
>
> Match
>
> ```
> Engineering
> ```
>
> Match
>
> ```
> Engineers
> ```
>
> Match
>
> ```
> Engineer!
> ```
>
> Match

---

> Also, how would I make this say starts with OR ends with engineer.

Simply flip around the REGEXP and set it as an *OR* statement:

```
SELECT * FROM app.desc_test t WHERE lower(t.desc) 
REGEXP '[[:<:]](engineer[[:alpha:]]*)|([[:alpha:]]*engineer)[[:>:]]';
```

Which tells the REGEXP to:
 *"look for engineer at the beginning of the word followed by any a-z values **or** look for any a-z values followed by engineer at the end of the word"*.

Comment: Same effect, but simpler:  `'[[:<:]](engineer[[:alpha:]]*[[:>:]]'`.  (Oh, `engineer123` might not work the same.)

Answer (score 1):

**For "desc starts with":**

"Starts with:

```
REGEXP:  '^engineer...'
LIKE:    'engineer%...'
```

Case folding:

```
If the collation of the column is `..._ci`, then do _not_ waste time with `LOWER()`.
```

So, this is optimal for finding `desc` that *starts with* "engineer" or "engineering" or "Engineer", etc:

```
   WHERE t.desc LIKE 'engineer%'
```

If you really meant "where desc *contains* 'engineer' or ...", then

```
   WHERE t.desc REGEXP '[[:<:]]engineer'
```

But a better way would be to use `FULLTEXT(desc)` and use this; it allows the word to be anywhere in `desc` and `desc` can be `TEXT`.

```
   WHERE MATCH(desc) AGAINST('+engineer*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

You must pick among the choices based on the actual requirements.  Meanwhile, here is the relative performance of them:

- `LOWER(desc) ...` -- poor, regardless of the rest of the clause
- `LIKE 'engineer%'` -- excellent if you have `INDEX(desc)`
- `LIKE 'engineer%'` -- poor with no index, or with prefixing: `INDEX(desc(100))`
- `MATCH...` -- excellent due to `FULLTEXT` index.
- `REGEXP ...` -- poor; will check every record

**For "there is a word that starts *or* ends with":**

You need to list positive and negative test cases:

```
engineering blah
The engineer.
MechanicalEngineering  -- neither starts nor ends at word boundary??
engineer
```

If all of those are valid, then this is the only viable answer:

```
    WHERE t.desc LIKE '%engineer%'
```

The equivalent `REGEXP 'engineer'` is slower (but has the same effect).

For other situations, I would look at something close to

```
   WHERE t.desc REGEXP '[[:<:]]engineer|engineer[[:>:]]'
```

which looks for a "word" that starts or ends with 'engineer'.  Note that this does not include 'MechanicalEngineering'.