# SQL regexp_replace String that ends with a dot

Tags: sql, regex, regexp-replace

I am working on a dtb makros model with SQL. I have a table with contacts and someone wrote Dr. in the firstname-colum, e.g. Dr. Anna. I only want the firstname without the Dr., so I just want the name Anna in the firstname column.

I have tried to get rid of it with

```
regexp_replace(trim(firstname), '\bDr.\b', '')
```

but it is not working. On the other hand, when I tried to get rid of Pfarrer (which is the German expression for priest) Anna, it worked.

I used

```
regexp_replace(trim(firstname), '\bPfarrer\b', '')
```

for this. I only got Anna back, as I wanted.

Why does it work with Pfarrer and not with Dr.?

Comment: It is a common regex issue. `\bDr\.\b` will only match in `Dr.A`, but not in `Dr. A` as a space is not a word char. Remove the last `\b`, or replace with `(?!\B\w)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004955/regex-using-word-boundary-but-word-ends-with-a-period

Comment: Removing the last \b worked for me, thank you!

Comment: You can also keep the last `\b` but add optional space before, if you don't want to remove standalone `Dr.` which is hypothetical. E.g. [`\bDr\. *\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ZVoNrn/1) will only match `Dr.` if followed by another word. Further don't forget to escape the dot from its special regex meaning, else it matches (almost) any charater.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you might want to remove all titles, including Mr., Mrs., Dr., and anything else following this pattern:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(firstname), '^\w+\.[ ]*', '') AS firstname
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: For some reason that one didn't work!

Comment: What is your SQL database?  Is it Oracle?

Comment: We are working with Amazon Athena and dbt

Comment: Try doubling up the backslashes: `REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(firstname), '^\\w+\\.[ ]*', '')`

Comment: Still doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: You should add sample `firstname` table data to your question.

Comment: Please remove the wrong answer and reclose the duplicate question. The real question was "Why does it work with Pfarrer and not with Dr.?" and [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004955/regex-using-word-boundary-but-word-ends-with-a-period) I used to close the question explains it.